# JSON Object Request

Tags: php, android, json, database

I am using a json object request to get information from a database that I have created. I am able with my android application to insert data into the database but now I want to check for example if the user created an user account.
I am getting a syntax error when I am trying to create the json object request. It is somehow a problem with the arguments but I do not understand what seems to be the problem. Both the url and the php files work fine.

```
String showUrl = "http://192.168.0.16/webapps/showUser.php";
public void searchLoginInfo(View view) {
    JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new /*HERE IS WHERE I GET THE ERROR*/ JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST,showUrl,(String)null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
            try {
                JSONArray users = response.getJSONArray("users");
                for (int i = 0; i < users.length(); i++){
                    JSONObject user = users.getJSONObject(i);
                    String username = user.getString("username");
                    String password = user.getString("password");
                    if (username.equals(myLoginList.get(0)) && password.equals(myLoginList.get(1))) {
                        Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Login Succesfull", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        Intent send = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, WelcomeActivity.class);
                        startActivity(send);
                        break;
                    }else{
                        Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Login Failed!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        Intent send = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
                        startActivity(send);
                    }
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Log.e("Volley Error", error.toString());
            NetworkResponse networkResponse = error.networkResponse;
            if (networkResponse != null) {
                Log.e("Status code", String.valueOf(networkResponse.statusCode));
            }
        }
    });
    requestQueue.add(jsonObjectRequest);
}
```

This is the error that I get: Error:(60, 98) error: incompatible types: String cannot be converted to JSONObject.

This is my showUser.php

```
<?php
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"]=="POST"){
    include 'connection.php';
    showUser();
}

function showUser(){
    global $connect;
    $query = "SELECT* FROM user;";
    $result = mysqli_query($connect,$query);
    $number_of_rows = mysqli_num_rows($result);
    $temp_array = array();
    if($number_of_rows>0){
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
            $temp_array[] = $row;
        }
    }
    header('Content-Type:application/json');
    json_encode(array("users"=>$temp_array));
    mysqli_close($connect);
}
?>
```

Comment: It would be better if you post the error

Comment: @SarmadAijaz Error:(60, 98) error: incompatible types: String cannot be converted to JSONObject

Comment: What is the value you are getting in `response` variable?

Comment: It doesn't even reach that line. The error is on line: JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new /*HERE IS WHERE I GET THE ERROR*/ JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST,showUrl,(String)null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() { @KNeerajLal

Comment: @KNeerajLal  Error:(60, 98) error: incompatible types: String cannot be converted to JSONObject

Comment: Can you show what the `showUser.php` script is returning?

Comment: @KNeerajLal I have updated my post and included the php script.

Comment: I think you missed an echo statement. Shouldn't it be `echo json_encode(...);`?

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the cast to `String`. Try this,

```
JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, showUrl, null,
    new Response.Listener<JSONObject>(){

        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

        }
    }
);
```

The error says the server is returning a `String` output. You can use a `StringRequest` to resolve the error,

```
StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, showUrl,
    new Response.Listener<String>() {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            Log.e("response", response);
        }
    },
    new Response.ErrorListener() {

        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

        }
    }
);
```

Comment: Check the edit and add the logcat output in the question.

Comment: Without casting it doesn't give me the error anymore, but it seems that it also doesn't reach the onResponse method.

Comment: Add a `Log` statement in the `onErrorResponse` method to see if there is an error.

Comment: I have updated my onErrorResponse method and by checking in the logcat I got this error: Volley Error: com.android.volley.ParseError: org.json.JSONException: Value Connection of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject     @KNeerajLal